# Why does my compiler show this error about my constexpr function?

Tags: c++, constructor, constexpr

Good evening,

i have to implement a class with a constexpr function, which returns a class member in a header file. The member is const and set in my constructor, so it won't change later in the program.

Header file implementation:

```
//Creates a PreAllocString object
#define CREATE (varName,size) {\
    char string##varName##[size] {'\0'};\
    PreAllocString varName (string##varName##, size);\
}

class PreAllocString 
{
private:
    char* string;
    const std::size_t size;
    std::size_t length = 0;
    operator const char *() const;
    operator const void *() const;
    const char & operator [] (const int idx);

public:
    //Constructor
    PreAllocString (char* string, const std::size_t size);
.
.
.
```

CPP File implementation:

```
#include "PreAllocString.h"

//Constructor
PreAllocString::PreAllocString (char* string, const std::size_t size) : string(string), size(size) {
    if (string != nullptr) {
        this->Empty();
    }
}
.
.
.
```

My compiler always shows:

```
In file included from src/PreAllocString.cpp:2:0:
include/PreAllocString.h:30:27: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function ‘std::size_t PreAllocString::SizeOf()’ is not a literal type
     constexpr std::size_t SizeOf () {
                           ^
include/PreAllocString.h:11:7: note: ‘PreAllocString’ is not literal because:
 class PreAllocString 
       ^
include/PreAllocString.h:11:7: note:   ‘PreAllocString’ is not an aggregate, does not have a trivial default constructor, and has no constexpr constructor that is not a copy or move constructor
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Read About [Literal Types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). Or just read the error-message you pasted.

Comment: What is this, C? In C++ you want to stay away from using macro definitions to create anything if you can, let alone using macro concatenation. Try templates they're built out at compile time, so should meet you requirements.

Comment: @Deduplicator i've already read the cppreference page about literals/constexpr and tried to understand what literal types are, i have also tried to use the type int instead of size_t as this is a literal type (if i'm getting it right?), but it didnt help out.

Comment: The **enclosing class** must be a literal type. And the error-message is quite explicit in what that means.

Comment: @Tzalumen My professor wants us to use the "CREATE" Makro, its an Embedded Systems lecture. I dont know anything about Templates and we have to hand the Code out till Wednesday. He said it is possible to solve the problem without templates. Is there a workaround for the problem or is there no other way?

Comment: Do you have a C++11 compiler?

Comment: In the lecture we are using the C++17 compiler.

Comment: What do you understand from the error message?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I am learning C++ since about 3 weeks, so my experience lacks of many standards. 
I think the SizeOf function and the PreAllocString Class is not a literal type, so it cant get used by the constexpr declaration. But neither do i understand what that means nor how i can fix it or why the class have to be a literal type?

Answer (score 0):

C guy here... I can't really help you write idiomatic C++, but I can try to explain why some things I can spot are errors.

---

```cxx
#define CREATE (varName,size) {\  
 ... 
}
```

---

This probably doesn't do what you expect.  I assume you're trying to define a function-like macro that expands to declare an array and a PreAllocString instance, so calling it like `CREATE(somename,somesize)` declares objects?
If so...

- you can't have whitespace between the macro name and its argument list.  If there's a space, anything that follows is part of the expansion.  eg:
  *`#define WORKS(varName) int varName`

  `#define DOESNT (varName) int varName`

  `WORKS(i);` >> `int i;`

  `DOESNT(i);` >> `(varName) int varName(i);`*
- the braces around your macro body are not syntax for macro definition, and having them there means they appear in the expansion.  ie,:
  *`CREATE(aName,6)`  ...

  >>  `{ char stringaName[6] {'\0'};              //technically no line break
           PreAllocString aName (stringaName, 6); }`*
- unless either the code you've shown is incomplete, or there's something about class constructors I don't understand at all... shouldn't your constructor's implementation be calling this thing?

---

```cxx
#define CREATE (varName,size) {\
    char string##varName##[size] {'\0'};\
    PreAllocString varName (string##varName##, size);\
}
```

*...`varName`* ***##*** ***`[`*** *size]...*
*...`varName`* ***##*** ***`,`*** *size...*

---

This doesn't seem to be manifesting an error (for now...), but this not a legal use of the token pasting operator and what you're getting here is undefined behavior.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace
Token pasting tries to combine two adjacent preprocessor tokens into a single new one... and `[`/`,` *('punctuators')* can't be part of identifier tokens. *(which, intent aside, are the only valid expansions for `varName` due to the **other** token pasting directive :p)*
The result taking place for this case seems to be... nothing.  You can just remove those directives; after concatenation fails, the unaltered separate tokens are just getting ingested separately as if nothing happened.  That outcome is essentially dumb luck, though.